# Windows7: explorer pseudocrash after login?

Tags: windows-7, crash, white-screen

Well, since yesterday after I log-in on Windows 7 (x64 Ultimate) I get the desktop as usual, but as soon as I try to interact with it with a click, it turns totally white.

The taskbar doesn't respond (like when explorer.exe crashes). I can interact with any programs that opend on startup but nothing else. I can press CTRL ALT DEL to get the menu where you can select log off, switch user, taskbar manager, etc. If I select the taskbar manager (or press CTRL SHIFT ESC) it brings it up, but it's blank and I can't interact with it.

I can boot up in Safe Mode (I'm posting this from Safe Mode with Networking) and everything looks fine. I tried running Malwarebytes but nothing comes up, I also ran chkdsk /r and the problem persists.

I should also add that this happens with the two Win users I have on this machine.

Any ideas?

*// Edit: Screenshot from msconfig.exe with all startup programs:*

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what's starting up in msconfig?

Comment: Sure, here you go, @MDMoore313: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/eTkO3XV.png).

Comment: Well, I should have done that before, but I just removed EVERYTHING from startup, except Comodo Firewall, and it started just fine. I'm posting in Windows Normal Mode now, so I'll be re-enabling them one by one and see which one was the culprit. Thank you @MDMoore313! Thanks @magicandre1981 for adding the screenshot on the OP, too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with cleaning up your msconfig definitely. From your screenshot I see at least a dozen items that could be killed, I typically on allow apps that go along with drivers to run at startup (NVIDIA's control panel or ATI's control panel, for example) and even then I experiment with turning those off just to see if they're really needed. I see you've turned some stuff off and that's a good start. Specifically, looking at your screenshot, I'd turn off:

> Everything in the top third of the screenshot, except for Comodo: that looks important
>
> Everything in the middle third of the screenshot.
>
> Everything in the bottom third of the screenshot that's not already disabled.

Then reboot into normal mode and see what's what. It's not a guaranteed fix but I would definitely start by eliminating anything extra that runs when you login.

Comment: Thank you so much @MDMoore313! The culprit was Skype. I'll try re-installing it to see if it's solved, but after re-enabling them one by one, it was that one that caused the problem. 

I removed a lot of them from startup anyway, I should keep an eye on that list so that it doesn't grow over time. Thanks again!